# E-mail address is not returning with facebook's graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im developing an android app that uses facebook login, and i would like to get the logged in facebook user's email, but somehow i cant.

So i started to play with facebook's [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and i can clearly see that the email field is not even in the returning data.

**My profile:**

[image]

**Graph API explorer:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must authorize a user with the "email" permission in order to get the email in the result of `/me`.

Comment: How can i do that...?

Comment: click on "get access token" in the api explorer and select the email permission. for doing it without the api explorer, you need to start reading the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2